# Craft 3 Controller giving 404

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, controller, 404

Updating a plugin to Craft 3 (also changed its name). I know this is probably something very simple, like capitalization, but can anyone point out what's wrong?

Firefox console shows a 404 for
`http://f.test/index.php?p=admin/actions/dryCalendar/calendarOccurrencesField/generateAjaxMiniCalendar`
and then
`Type error: Response is null`

So perhaps Craft is getting the request, but `$this->returnJson($response);` isn't terminating the request, i.e. Craft continues to try to find a page to match?

My files are set up like this:

```
DryCalendar.php
controllers/DryCalendar_CalendarOccurrencesFieldController.php
```

is

```
<?php
namespace Craft;
//namespace kr37\drycalendar\controllers;
use Craft;
use craft\base\Controller;
class DryCalendar_CalendarOccurrencesFieldController extends BaseController
{
    public function actionGenerateAjaxMiniCalendar() {
        ...
        $this->returnJson($response);    
    }   
}
```

and in my Garnish js is

```
Craft.postActionRequest(                   
    'dryCalendar/calendarOccurrencesField/generateAjaxMiniCalendar', 
    data, 
    function(response) {
         ...
    });
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craft 3 action routes are `snake-case` rather than `camelCase` thus your route needs to be `plugin-handle/controller-handle/function-name` instead of `pluginHandle/controllerName/functionName`

Your Controllers namespace must be `prefix\namespace\name\controllers` so in your case it could be `kr37\drycalendar\controllers` not Craft.

Furthermore you don't need to include your plugin name to the classname anymore. Your controller name can be

`CalendarOccurrencesFieldController`

Your action will then be `drycalendar/calendar-occurrences-field/generate-ajax-mini-calendar`

Keep in mind you'll have to create [routes](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/26454/resolving-the-entry-variable-for-custom-routes-somewhere-but-a-twig-template/26455#26455) of you don't use the [action](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#action-params) parameter in your request. Currently you are trying to access your controller via cp/site route, not via action route

Comment: Snake-case-was-it, thank you! I think, Robin, that you are rewriting my plugin for me. Very kind.